# How to highlight code based on range and style

Tags: rust, syntax-highlighting

I have a lexer that generates token types and ranges, and I want to write a code highlighter.

I consider arranging the intervals in order according to the starting offset.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CodeHighlighter<'i, 's> {
    /// raw text
    text: &'i str,
    /// start -> (styles , end)
    intervals: BTreeMap<usize, IntervalRepr<'s>>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct IntervalRepr<'s> {
    styles: BTreeSet<&'s str>,
    end: usize,
}
```

Whenever a new range is inserted, the behavior is determined based on whether there is an overlap.

This is my implementation:

```rust
impl<'i, 's> CodeHighlighter<'i, 's> {
    pub fn new(text: &'i str) -> Self {
        let mut interval = BTreeMap::new();
        // Mark all code as no style
        interval.insert(0, IntervalRepr { styles: Default::default(), end: text.len() });
        Self { text, intervals: interval }
    }
    pub fn mark_span(&mut self, span: Range<usize>, style: &'s str) {
        match self.intervals.get(&span.start) {
            Some(_) => {
                match self.intervals.get(&span.end) {
                    // simple case, no need change old interval
                    Some(_) => self.mark_span_unchecked(span, style),
                    // remark end position
                    None => {
                        let (_, last_span) = self.intervals.range(span.end..).next().unwrap();
                        let new_end = last_span.end;
                        let new_styles = last_span.styles.clone();
                        self.intervals.remove(&span.end);
                        self.intervals.entry(span.end).or_insert(IntervalRepr { styles: new_styles, end: new_end });
                        self.mark_span_unchecked(span, style)
                    }
                }
            }
            None => {
                // truncate the previous span
                let prev_span = self.intervals.range_mut(..span.start).next_back();
                if let Some((_, prev_inner)) = prev_span {
                    prev_inner.end = span.start;
                }
                // insert start position
                let (_, next_span) = self.intervals.range(span.start..).next().unwrap();
                let new_end = next_span.end;
                let new_styles = next_span.styles.clone();
                self.intervals.remove(&span.start);
                self.intervals.entry(span.start).or_insert(IntervalRepr { styles: new_styles, end: new_end });
                self.mark_span_unchecked(span, style)
            }
        }
    }
    fn mark_span_unchecked(&mut self, span: Range<usize>, style: &'s str) {
        for (_, inner) in self.intervals.range_mut(span) {
            inner.styles.insert(style);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn colorize() {
    let mut code_render = CodeHighlighter::new("public class Main {}");
    code_render.mark_span(0..6, "keyword");
    code_render.mark_span(7..12, "keyword");
    code_render.mark_span(13..17, "class");
    println!("{:#?}", code_render);
}
```

But there seems to be a problem with my handling of overlaps, and it often panic.

I also don't know if this data structure is efficient and appropriate.

How should I fix my code?

Comment: What if you have two intervals that start on the same position, but have different lengths?

Comment: @Jmb The range where `new.end` is located will be divided into two, the left range copies the original style and adds a new style. Oh, there seems to be a problem with my idea. In the first stage, we only need to distinguish whether to cut new.start and new.end. In the second stage, we directly color all the intervals in the middle.